# Outlook 365 new message sound

Tags: microsoft-outlook, system-sounds

Hy, I have a strange issue which I can't resolve. I have windows 10 and outlook 365.

When a new e-mail arrives, the computer makes a default sound and that's ok.
I wanted to change the sound to something else. I went to the control panel-Sound-Sounds tab.
On that tab I changed the sound for the event New mail notification (I browsed for a .waw file, selected it, pressed the button Test, that sound played correctly, selected apply and OK).
What happens next is a mystery. When a new mail arrives in outlook, it doesn't play the sound that I selected, but instead the sound that is defined in Sound-Sounds-Notification event.
I tried to change that sound, under the Notification I selected the desired .waw file, pressed Test, the sound played correctly, and pressed ok. After that outlook no longer played any sound.
My .waw file is 3 seconds long, 101kb large, it has a bitrate 256kbps. I believe the .waw file is correct because when testing it it plays correctly. I don't understand why windows refuses to play it upon message arrival.

I went back to the Sound-Sounds tab to check whether the setting remained and it did. After selecting the New mail notification Event and pressing the Test button the desired sound played as a test.

And one more thing. I'm not an admin for my PC and I can't move the .waw file to C:\Windows\media folder because I need admin password. Instead, the .waw file is in "C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\some name of the folder" folder.

Comment: The WAV file should be with the rest of the Windows Sound files. You need to do this. Ask your company support people to move the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I noticed that you are using the .waw file as the new sound. As I know, [only .wav audio files are supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-sound-played-when-an-email-message-arrives-cbf254a8-008c-4dce-a02f-b9c87fa8097a). So, please try the correct file format and see if the issue has any difference.

By the way, agree with @John mentioned, please move your sound file to the default folder with administrator rights, and see if it works.