# Web Outlook 365 default sound

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I can't seem to make this sound change. Everything that I have found says that I need to go to system sounds and change the New Mail Notification and that will do it only it doesn't. It doesn't matter what I change it to, it doesn't change. I even changed my sounds profile from Windows Default (Modified) to None and it still makes the same sound. (I don't want it to be nothing, I just tried that as a check to ensure I wasn't changing the wrong option or something silly)

I just started at a new place and it is their outlook.office.com site that is going DING DING when I get new messages. I need to change it to something else.

I have admin rights on this system, it is my personal PC and I don't have issues changing sounds for other things - just this online outlook. What am I missing?

Please note that this is NOT a duplicate of [Outlook 365 new message sound](https://superuser.com/questions/1590294/outlook-365-new-message-sound)

Comment: Outlook Options, Mail - Turn the Outlook Sound OFF (uncheck it).  Close Outlook.  Now try changing the Windows Sound. Restart and re-enable the Outlook Sound.

Comment: So I have to download and install outlook in order to make a change to a webpage?

Comment: If you are using Web Outlook, you need to ask your Company Outlook People. Your post should be edited to say Web Outlook.

Comment: Hmmm, they said they don't have control over OWA. I guess I'll load it locally and see if I can get control of it.

Comment: Let us know - thanks.

Comment: @John Absolutely will! I tried to be lazy and just get away with outlook (PWA) and no joy so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I created an [Edge add-on](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/web-outlook-custom-notifi/hfgdhjohglbjgjhjcbhgjijnlibkocmk) to deal with new email / calendar reminder notifications

---

It has been very difficult to find a way to replace the sound… In my case, I wanted to change the one from the calendar reminder.

I finally did it by following these steps:

1. Install Requestly ([here is the link for Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/requestly-redirect-url-/ehghoapnlpepjmfbgaomdiilchcjemak)) – it should also work with any add-on that can insert a JavaScript in the page, like Violentmonkey
2. Create new rule "**Insert Scripts**"
3. In the criteria, put: "URL Contains [https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox/id/"](https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox/id/%22)
4. Let "JS" for the "Language", "Code" for the "Code Source", and "After Page Load" for the "Insert"
5. Enter the below code to the script area

```javascript
console.log("### Code injection from Requestly");
// below it's the Base64 version of the ArrayBuffer for mp3  
// the content is too long for SuperUser, so you can check at 
// https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/ec5f8508202ed8a0c3f7ad18c1de872a   
const reminder = `SUQzBAAAAAAAI1RT[…]VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVU=`;

// Below is a function that converts a base64 string to an ArrayBuffer
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64String) {
  const binaryString = atob(base64String);
  const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
    uint8Array[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}

// to return an audio object
async function myCalendarReminderSound () {
  let t = await new Response(base64ToArrayBuffer(reminder), {
    status: 200, // Set the desired status code
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' } // Set the desired content type
  });
  let i = await t.arrayBuffer();
  let r = new AudioContext();
  return r.decodeAudioData(i);
}

// we override the "fetch" function
var originalFetch = fetch;
fetch = function (url) {
  // we want to replace the calendar reminder sound, so we check the URL
  if (typeof url === "string" && url.endsWith("sounds/notifications/reminder.mp3")) {
    console.log("### Inject a new calendar reminder sound");
    // wait 1 second delay to avoid overlapping the original sound
    setTimeout(() => {
      myCalendarReminderSound().then(e => {
        let r = new AudioContext();
        let t = r.createBufferSource();
        t.buffer = e,
        t.connect(r.destination),
        t.start(0);

        // also show a desktop notification
        new Notification("Calendar Event", {
          body: "A calendar event has been triggered."
        });
      })
    }, 1000)
  }

  // Call the original fetch method
  return originalFetch.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

6. Save and reload the Web Outlook: you should now hear an additional sound for Calendar Reminder, as well as a Desktop Notification

It would be better to have an add-on doing all this stuff… maybe one day I'll create it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The sound cant be changed because it is being requested by the web outlook live from: https://res-h3.public.cdn.office.net/owamail/20230407001.14/resources/sounds/notifications/newmail.mp3

maybe the requested url can be rerouted???

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).